# How to count (SELECT some table)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TABLENAME
FROM BASE5.SYS_FORM_INFO
where ISFLAG = 1
```

Result:

[image]

When i use count() to include it.

```
SELECT count(*) from (
    SELECT TABLENAME
    FROM BASE5.SYS_FORM_INFO
    where ISFLAG = 1
)
```

Result:

[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]')' syntax error near

```
SELECT count(*) from FE_APP5.dbo.FT_001_84D7B91BDD9F26F2178E
```

Result :

[image]

SO, my question is how to count some tables that i selected  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an alias for the subquery:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT TABLENAME
      FROM BASE5.SYS_FORM_INFO
      WHERE ISFLAG = 1
     ) x;
```

I assume you know that the subquery is not necessary:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM BASE5.SYS_FORM_INFO
WHERE ISFLAG = 1
```

Comment: No column names are specified for column 1 for'x'.

Comment: [SQL]SELECT count(*) 
from (
   SELECT TABLENAME
   FROM BASE5.SYS_FORM_INFO
    where ISFLAG = 1 
   ) x

Comment: @xojisi . . . SQL doesn't care whether or not columns in the outer query have aliases.  Your application seems to.